# angularjs directive to check if min. one item in a list of checkboxes is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which should check if at least one item in a list of checkbox items is selected. If not it should show a error message under the list. Therefore I created this directive:

```
.directive('validateServices', [function () {

function validate(services) {
  for(var x= 0;x<services.length;x++) {
    if(services[x].selected) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$validators.emptyServices = function (modelValue) {
      return validate(modelValue);
    }
  }
}
}]);
```

And the usage:

```
<ul class="list" validate-services ng-model="pricelist">
  <li class="item title-left"><b>Prestaties</b></li>
  <li ng-repeat="price in pricelist" class="item item-checkbox" ng-click="calculateSum()">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="price.selected">
    </label>
    {{price.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<div role="alert">
  <span class="error" ng-if="submitted && pricelist.$error.emptyServices">
      Vul een prestatie
  </span>
</div>
```

But the alert never shows up even if the values are correct. What is wrong with this directive?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/007design/N3w8Z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ngModelController**

In order to get validation with the `ngModelController` you need to have a form element or `ng-form` directive ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)).  To create the conditional error message you need access to the ngModel's `$error` object, so you can tell when it's valid/invalid.

```
<div ng-form="priceForm">
  ...
  <ul class="list" validate-services name="plField" ng-model="pricelist">
  ...
```

here's what the conditional would look like:

```
<span class="error" ng-if="priceForm.plField.$error.emptyServices">
```

**directive**

In the directive link function you'll need to setup a manual `$watch` on the `ngModel` value and call your validation function when ngModel changes:

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {

  // this sets your ngModel's validity based on your 
  // validation function 
  ngModel.$setValidity('emptyServices', validate(newValue));
}, true);
```

You can see a working example in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/B1MPNBR5EC7YARKdvTO2?p=preview